# handle Exception PermissionError of xlswriter in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, xlsxwriter

I use `XlsxWriter` in my Python3.3 app and when excel file is opened and run py script this error happened and i can not handled with except `except PermissionError`,

Error:

> `Exception PermissionError: PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied') in <bound method Workbook.__del__ of <xlsxwriter.workbook.Workbook object at 0x00000000032C3400>> ignored`

How i can handled this error with try?

Comment: Try except Exception as msg:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add try/except around the `close()` to handle conditions where the file is already open and locked by Excel.

```
try:
    workbook.close()
except:
    # Handle your exception here.
    print("Couldn't create xlsx file")
```

If required you can add specific exception handlers for specific conditions.

Comment: Can you give an example of an exception to add in order to unlock the file? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
import xlsxwriter

try:
    # Create a workbook and add a worksheet.
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Expenses01.xlsx')
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

    # Some data we want to write to the worksheet.
    expenses = (
        ['Rent', 1000],
        ['Gas',   100],
        ['Food',  300],
        ['Gym',    50],
    )

    # Start from the first cell. Rows and columns are zero indexed.
    row = 0
    col = 0

    # Iterate over the data and write it out row by row.
    for item, cost in (expenses):
        worksheet.write(row, col,     item)
        worksheet.write(row, col + 1, cost)
        row += 1

    # Write a total using a formula.
    worksheet.write(row, 0, 'Total')
    worksheet.write(row, 1, '=SUM(B1:B4)')

    workbook.close()
except:
    #
    #DO WHAT YOU WANT TO DO
```

Try this.